# loop back to first slide in a slider when user reaches last slide on the carousel

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to recreate this slider: https://bewegen.com/en its under the Accelerating Bike Share section.
I managed to create the count slider but having trouble getting it back to count 1 when it hits the end count of 9 - smoothly have it loop back to the start.

How to get the count to loop back to the start like in the example above?

```
Here is my codepen work: https://codepen.io/harp30/pen/GYEXXe
```

Thank you.

Comment: the example you provided does indeed loop back to 1. I'm not sure what else you're trying to do?

Comment: its not looping like the one in the example.

Comment: your codepen example does loop. It works fine for me.

Comment: Most carousel libraries handle this by "cloning" each slide, putting half the clones before and half the clones after. This is an example of what I mean: https://i.stack.imgur.com/esdql.png the idea being that when you hit the next button on the last slide, you're going to a clone of the first slide.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your `next()` function like this:

```
function next() {
  count = count + 1;
  if (count > num.length - 1) {
    // Clone first item and add it to the end
    var clone = num[0].cloneNode(true);
    countItemNumberHolder.appendChild(clone);

    // Let the transition happen normally
    TweenMax.to(countItemNumberHolder, 0.4, { y: -289 * count });

    // Wait for transition to finish and reset transform to 0 without animation
    setTimeout(function() {
      TweenMax.to(countItemNumberHolder, 0, { y: 0 });
      countItemNumberHolder.removeChild(clone);
    }, 300);

    // Now reset counter
    count = 0;

  } else {
    TweenMax.to(countItemNumberHolder, 0.4, { y: -289 * count });
  }
}
```

Essentially, when you reach the last element, clone the first element and let the transition happen normally. Once the transition is complete, reset your transform to `0` without animation, and remove the cloned element. Similarly, you can do the same for the previous button.

However, you will probably want to remove and add the event listeners during the transition, otherwise, if the user clicks rapidly, it might lead to unexpected behavior.

A much cleaner implementation of an infinite carousel can be found here:
https://codepen.io/matthewwilliams/pen/Vayrjv